# Do we need to update Xcode to use the latest version of iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I upgrade from iOS 9.3 Beta 2 to iOS 9.3 Beta 3 last week on my iPhone 6s, I had to use the computer. Then, when I try to run the app, they couldn't detect the phone because it is on Xcode 7.3 Beta 2. Should I upgrade Xcode on the App Store, or should I install it manually, I want it to be less than 2 hours. Can I do that?

Comment: If you have the newest iOS beta, you need the newest Xcode beta. Since it's a beta, you have to download it from the Apple developer site and install it manually.

Comment: Well, should we know about iOS to actually develop an app? Should we know when phones are announced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to have the latest Xcode beta version to test and develop for the last iOS beta version . This is simply because the latest Xcode Beta contains the latest APIs from Apple that are needed to make successful iOS apps